# InvalidKeyException while encrypting data

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

I know that there are many threads over this , but i am not able to find solution with them.
Problem Statement:
Need to encrypt data. Below is my code:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

public class CryptoUtil {

    private static final String AES = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";

    public String encryptMessage(final String message, final byte[] dataKey) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(dataKey, AES);
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] encryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessage);
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new Exception("Error while encrypting application credentials", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to do it using BountyCastle service provider. So i followed the steps mentioned [here](https://sceweb.uhcl.edu/yang/teaching/JDK_JCE_environment_Configuration.htm) and [this](https://github.com/wultra/powerauth-server/wiki/Installing-Bouncy-Castle). I am using JAVA 11, but i switched to JAVA 8 to follow mentioned link.
In my code i added static block to add BountyCastle as service provider

```
static {
    BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(bouncyCastleProvider);
  }
```

But, it is not getting added as verified providers. So i am getting the issue.
Any idea how to handle. How to add BouncyCastle as verified provider.
I am running on local machine , and need to create JAR.

Comment: I think "SecretKeySpec(dataKey, AES);" should be:  SecretKeySpec(dataKey, "AES"); .  You don't specify mode or padding for secretkeyspec, that's specified when you create the cipher.  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory

Comment: @Chandra Please give us the stack trace of the InvalidKeyException if one is being thrown.

Comment: @TheGreatContini - you are right, it should be  SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(byte[] of key, "AES");

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has answered this, so I'll just post an answer with the comment I had above.  I have not tested it so I leave that part to you.

When you do `Cipher.getInstance()`, it is correct to have "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" (for some weird definition of "correct", where Java providers believe PKCS5 padding = PKCS7 padding, but never mind that).

But when you create the key, it is not correct to have the mode and padding in there.  Instead, they just want the algorithm.  So try:

```
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(dataKey, "AES");
```

The change is the quotes around "AES", rather than using AES="AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding".

Not sure if that will fix your problem, but should be a step in the right direction (I hope).